# what is the difference between .NET Framework Develop Pack and .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have navigate to https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows
to download .net core SDK , then i saw there is 3 build apps

1. .Net Core
2. Visual Studio
3. .NET Framework Develop Pack

Can anyone explain what is the difference between 1st one and 3rd one ?

Comment: sorry . kind of duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is .NET Core which is a smaller subset of the .NET framework. .NET Core was largely for web apps and web workers, but it was [announced yesterday](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/) that soon .NET Core will support desktop applications as well. Not all assemblies are available in Core, but it has a smaller package size and will run on any platform.

.NET Framework is the one people usually refer to when they say ".NET", which is the full-featured framework that is used to build VB.NET and C# applications.

A great read about the difference in use for server applications (which is where the real details lie) can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server).